# Stuck on pset 3 (Runoff) HELPP

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, nested-loops, cs50

Can someone tell me why my code doesn't work.

here's its description https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/3/runoff/.

the error is most probably outside of the main function.

**edit - the issue has been resolved, below code is working solution to the pset**

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    // TODO

    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name,candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            return true;
        }


    }

    return false;
}

// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
void tabulate(void)
{
    // TODO
    for(int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if(candidates[preferences[i][j]].eliminated == false)
            {
                candidates[preferences[i][j]].votes += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(candidates[i].votes > (voter_count / 2))
        {
            printf("%s\n",candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has
int find_min(void)
{
    // TODO
    int min = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(candidates[i].eliminated == false)
        {
            if(min >= candidates[i].votes)
            {
                min = candidates[i].votes;
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}

// Return true if the election is tied between all candidates, false otherwise
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    // TODO
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {

        if(candidates[i].eliminated == false && candidates[i].votes != min)
        {
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

// Eliminate the candidate (or candidates) in last place
void eliminate(int min)
{
    // TODO
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            if(candidates[i].votes == min)
            {
                candidates[i].eliminated = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I tried using debugger but the code just keeps on looping and i cant seem to find the error.

i also cant seem to view the elements inside the structure and array in the debugger which in turn makes me unable to debug properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be more, but there's this at least:

```
void tabulate(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) { // <== counting up to ~100 voters
        if(!candidates[i].eliminated) // <== indexing array whose max dimension is 9
            candidates[preferences[i][0]].votes += 1;
        else {
            for(int j = 1; j <= candidate_count; j++)
                if(candidates[i].eliminated) { // <== and again, here
                    candidates[preferences[i][j]].votes += 1;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Having found at least two problems, I'm won't be correcting the code. This is "homework" for the OP to do.

Comment: thanks alot for narrowing it down. I will look into this and hope to solve it on my own

Comment: @Fe203 can you please look at my code once again. I made some changes on the mistakes you have pointed out. yet my code is not working

Comment: Had a look at `tabulate()`. As written, it's too complicated. It's giving votes to candidates who've been eliminated... Think: for each voter, scan the voter's preferences and give the vote to the first candidate who has NOT been eliminated. It's no more than a nested pair of `for()` loops and only one `if()` condition. Draw out the logic and think it through. Only then should you return to the code to correct it. (Haven't looked at any other code here. You are the one taking the course; not me.)

Comment: Out of boredom I looked at your code again... Think your way through `find_min()`... The variable `min` starts at zero, then the code loops looking for candidate(s) receiving fewer than the current minimum number of votes (already zero)... Programming requires _thinking_ about the values of variables as they are used.

Comment: @Fe203 thanks man. i resolved the issue with find_min(). Now i will try going through the tabulate() as you said. i really suck at programming ig

Comment: @Fe203 OMG bro, thanks alot i got the solution. You have been a huge help .May the gods of progamming bless you.

Comment: Glad you found the solution. Coding, like any skill, can be acquired by diligent work and exercise... It's up to you to decide if you're drawn to it sufficiently to invest the blood, sweat and tears... Best wishes...

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to determine where in the program the program is getting stuck?

While in the debugger you can do a couple things to see elements in the array: in the code body, hover over the array and the elements will pop up; you can also click the + in the watch section on the left pane (under VARIABLES) and add the array there so you can keep track of it even if you enter or exit a function

Comment: no i cant. the program keeps on looping when i tried with debugger and when I meant by array was a two dimensional array

Comment: though is it possible to view elements inside a two dimensional array